# Подскажите как правильно сделать UPDATE картинки через форму

Tags: javascript, java, html, jquery, crud

Есть spring mvc и простая форма (для примера), соответственно эту форму использую и для создания и для редактирования контакта (подтягиваю данные из базы).

```
<form>
  <input id="name" type="text">
  ...
  <input id="photo" type="file">
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Трабл у меня возникает если пользователь не меняет фото при редактировании, тогда при отправке формы в теге `<input id="photo" type="file">`будет пусто и существующее фото успешно заменятся на `NULL`. Есть ли способы решения на стороне клиента? и как вообще правильно такие вещи делать?

Comment: как самый банальный/грубый задать полю фото значение required.

Comment: хм, проверять на NULL и не обновлять?

Answer (score 1):

Если это обязательное действие - ставить полю required.

А если это допустимо ( не грузить фото ) - проверять кол-во файлов, и если файлов нет  - то не не заменять фото

Comment: Поле не обязательное, т.е. вариант required отпадает. По проверке на кол-во файлов, а также на  null тут выходит следующее, в контроллере я из полей формы собираю объект и потом его отправляю в базу (описал сокращенно)  Если нет поля фото надо проверить а было ли оно, т.е. запрос к базе - проверяем что там записано и что имеем и т.д. Мне кажется что как-то сложно.

Comment: Проверяй через жску, если файлов нет - ставь ему disabled. Вроде если disabled оно не отправляет